# Only run JavaScript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I have a little script that only seems to work correctly in Chrome. It's not a big problem, however the negative effects it has in other browsers is annoying, so I'd like to only run it in Chrome.

This is my current working script that runs in all browsers:

```
function psn() {
var myElement = document.getElementById('noti');
if(window.addEventListener) {
   // Normal browsers
   myElement.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', contentChanged, false);
} else
   if(window.attachEvent) {
      // IE
      myElement.attachEvent('DOMSubtreeModified', contentChanged);
   }
function contentChanged() {
   // this function will run each time the content of the DIV changes
         document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();   
         var vid = document.getElementById("audiotag1");
vid.volume = 1;


}}
setTimeout(function () {psn()}, 2000);
```

And this is what I've tried already to make it run only in Chrome, which made the script stop working all together:

```
function psn() {
var myElement = document.getElementById('noti');
if(window.addEventListener) {
   // Normal browsers
   myElement.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', contentChanged, false);
} else
   if(window.attachEvent) {
      // IE
      myElement.attachEvent('DOMSubtreeModified', contentChanged);
   }
function contentChanged() {
   // this function will run each time the content of the DIV changes
         document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();   
         var vid = document.getElementById("audiotag1");
vid.volume = 1;


}}
var isChrome = !!window.chrome;
if (isChrome) {

setTimeout(function () {psn()}, 2000);
}
```

Anyone know why this is just stopping everything completely?

Comment: **Warning! This is a side note** Why `setTimeout(psn, 2000);`? Maybe you can edit your script to work in most browsers... Checking for just chrome isn't a good practice. It would make sense to have your script only work in 3 browsers.

Comment: Where did you get `window.chrome` from? You should try: `var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0 ? true : false;`

Comment: Actually, `window.chrome` is more reliable than browser sniffing.

Comment: I don't do much JavaScript so I wasn't sure on the proper way to test the browser. Most pages I found showed that the way I put it is the way to test for Chrome :/

Comment: Also, the `setTimeout` is there because it seems to stop the script firing for a couple of seconds on page load, which is a work around I've had to use for an error I couldn't otherwise bypass

Comment: I'll be honest, `somethinghere`'s comment made it all work the way I want it to. Like I say, it's not an important part of my site, and users can turn it off if they'd like, so it's not a big deal if one browser only supports it. Besides, most of my users use Chrome as it is

Comment: You could try `window.onload` or jQueries `$(document).ready()` instead of that timeout, as slow connections would still fire this before the page is loaded.

Comment: the javascript console says...? what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to not have to do specific browser detection, but an easy way to see if you are using Chrome or not is the following:

```
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0 ? true : false;
```

This will populate isChrome with either `true` of `false`.

Comment: This will not detect Chrome browsers running under iOS. The word 'Chrome' does not appear in the userAgent string.

Comment: @RandyMinder Thats because Chrome browsers under iOS _arent really chrome_ and therefore do not support Chrome specific features anyway. They are safari with a different front-end and google services.

Comment: The mobile version of the site will be completely different anyway, so this is perfect for my needs. Thanks dude